How to render Emoji or other special symbols in C# coming from YouTube RSS Feed
How to display strings below with a smiley face or other sybmbols in C# View coming from YouTube RSS Feed:

Have you ever seen THIS on TOUR? 

media:titleNEAR ACE from Caitlin Clark </media:title>
Nothing like the support of family ❤️


At the moment I get this just using @item.Title:

Have you ever seen THIS on TOUR? ðŸ˜³

I also tried @Html.Raw(item.Title) and same result.
